# JazzyViewPager CubeOut Vertical Rotation instead of Horizontal Rotation

Tags: android

I just finished implementing the JazzyViewPager on my app. I'm using the "CubeOut" Transition Effect, and it works great. Unfortunatelly my project requirement is to use that CubeOut Transition Effect but the rotation should be done vertically not horizontally as the CubeOut does it.

I'm wondering if somene out there as done it before or if there is a way to modify the code so the CubeOut effect can be done vertically.

Any help would be really appreciate.
Thanks.